# Validation error message doesn't appear in View?

Tags: php, codeigniter

My `$msg` doesn't appear in the view when the user's input is invalid. No error show, just that the error msg doesn't appear. Below is my controller and view.

**Login controller**

```
public function index($msg = null){
    $data['msg'] = $msg;
    $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
}

public function process(){
    $this->load->model('login_model');

    $result = $this->login_model->validate();

    if(!$result){
        $msg = '<font color=red>Invalid username and/or password.</font><br />';
        $this->index();
    }else{
        // if validated to member area
        redirect('home');
    }
}
```

**my `login_view`**

```
<?php if(! is_null($msg)) echo $msg;?>
```

the `$this->index` works but the `$msg` is always `null`, I wonder why.

Comment: Stop using `font` tag; it has been deprecated from HTML specification for years!

Comment: Without knowing anything about the internals of codeigniter - is this a scope issue? How does `$msg` get passed to your login view? It's a local variable inside your `process` method, which means that it's probably out of scope elsewhere

Comment: Yes it is a scope issue between those functions, but if you create the view data and a property of the object - they will be able to be accessed. CI will pass the variables to the function from the URL path data - or they way i showed below. - Also , Try to keep your HTML markup out of the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function index($msg = null){

    $data['msg'] = $msg;
    $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
}

public function process(){
    $this->load->model('login_model');

    $result = $this->login_model->validate();

    if(!$result){
        $msg = '<font color=red>Invalid username and/or password.</font><br />';
        $this->index($msg);
    }else{
        // if validated to member area
        redirect('home');
    }
}
```

You need to pass the variable , since it is not in scope of that other function -  i am going to create another answer with another way to do this another way as an example. -- try to keep HTML out of the controller  if you can .

Comment: I thought     $this->load->view('login_view', $data); will pass to the view? need to pass again?

Comment: See comment above . Also I would recommend you look in to 
CodeIgniter Flash Data - you would have to redirect though, which can be an advantage if you want to also clear the post data . It creates a session variable for the next request -  https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $viewData = array(); 

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct(); 
}

public function index(){
    $this->load->view('login_view', $this->viewData);
}

public function process(){
    $this->load->model('login_model');

    if(!$result = $this->login_model->validate()){
        $this->viewData['msg'] = array(
            'msg' => 'Put your message Here',
            'class' => 'error'
        );
        return $this->index();
    }
    redirect('home');
}
```

> ////////////////////////////////////////////
>
> view file

```
<?php 

    if(isset($msg['msg'], $msg['class'])){ 

        echo '<span class="'.$msg['class'].'" >' .  $msg['msg'] . '</span>';

    }

?>
```

Comment: Why do you make 2 answers?

Comment: Because i believe that "just having it work" isn't good enough sometimes. I guess that my question would be , Why didn't you make 1 ?

Comment: Then i would recommend you to edit your accepted answer! and not make 2!

Comment: in index function $this->viewData solved the scope problem? I don't get this, can someone explain this more?

Comment: that would be settings those on a property of the object - ( which all methods would have access to ) - the way you were doing it before was a local variable scoped to that function only, which is why you would need to pass it...